# SQL server delete large number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have found similar posts, but still didn't help my issue so i'll try my luck creating this one.
I have a large table (around 500 million entries) and i need to remove half of it by a simple where clause: "where Resolution = 100".
I need to keep the other half, therefore, i cannot truncate the table.
Same if i copy the other half in another table, it will just take too much time, and this is a production database...

I also tried deleting them in batches of 10k, but no success.

Any other idea is much appreciated.

Edit: forgot to mention, the recovery mode is set to simple, but still...

Comment: *but no success* means?

Comment: what is the reason for the failure of 10K batches? can you please provide the code snippet used for batching

Comment: Do you have an index on that column? What does "no sucess" mean? Do you need to do this inside some kind of maintenance window?

Comment: Deleting in batches can be made to work, though. Source: having a database that does this on a daily basis for several million rows. You have to narrow down what you mean by "success" -- if the issue is simply "it takes too long", there may be little recourse -- but what's "too long"? Is this a one-off action or something regular? How about creating a view or function or other alternative that removes the rows you no longer want from consideration without deleting them, so you can do the physical deleting at a slower pace?

Comment: Try adapting this solution already posted: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26931016/revisions

Comment: Before executing the delete command I would drop all the indexes and triggers of the table, recreating them after the execution. It's faster to recreate an index once than keep updating it at every row deleted.

Comment: No success means it takes a very long time. I did what @MarcGuillot suggested: i deleted all the indexes of the table and then deleted the entries in batches. Also specified "with (tablock)" and everything went smooth. Deleted in batches like 35 million entries in 5~10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery mode simple will not help if the log can not expand - it drops the log after the transaction, but the transaction is STILL a delete of 250 million rows. Small, btw.

What you can do is:

- Run this as a script
- Delete smaller amount of rows in a loop.

Delete top 10000000 is valid - and you can do so with your conditions until @@rowcount = 0, which indicates no rows where found.

This keeps the transactions smaller, which avoids the super large transaction that may blow your transaction log - which is what I can see as issue because you decide in your wisdom to just state "does not work" and not give the error it gives you.